# Cannot group data in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have a question about a LINQ grouping.

I thought that grouping would be a simple matter of using the `GroupBy` function on the result set and specifying what to group it by. However my items appear to not be grouping together and instead are displaying as if the `GroupBy` function wasn't there. I want to group by the `itemPk`, but I'm can't seem to do it. I have tried grouping by both `category.ItemFk` and `Item.Itempk`, but no luck. Could someone give me a pointer on this?

```
        var itemIds = items.Select(i => i.ItemId).ToList();
        var itemAndCatJoin =

        from item in Context.SCS_Items
        join category in Context.SCS_ItemCategories
        on item.ItemPk equals category.ItemFk
        into temp
        from category in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new ExportItemTable
        {
        Category = category,
        Item = item
        };

        return itemAndCatJoin.Where(i => itemIds.Contains(i.Item.ItemPk))
                        .GroupBy(n => new {n.Item, n.Category})
                       .Select(i => new ExportableItem
                       {

                           ItemPk = i.Key.Item.ItemPk,
                           Name = i.Key.Item.Name,
                           Description = i.Key.Item.Description,
                           Price = i.Key.Item.Price,
                           Category = i.Key.Category.Category.Category_Name,
                           GLDepartment = i.Key.Category.GL_Department.Name ?? "",
                           GLName = i.Key.Category.GL_Name.Name ?? "",
                           StartDate = i.Key.Item.StartDate,
                           EndDate = i.Key.Item.EndDate,
                           FiscalYear = i.Key.Item.SCS_FiscalYear.Name,
                           School = i.Key.Item.School != null ? i.Key.Item.School.School_Name : i.Key.Item.Board.Board_Name,
                           Beneficiary = i.Key.Item.SCS_Beneficiary.Name,
                           Quantity = i.Key.Item.MaxQuantity,
                           Deleted = i.Key.Item.DeletedFlag,
                           OptionalStudents = i.Key.Item.SCS_Attachments.Where(a => !a.IsRequired).SelectMany(a => a.SCS_StudentAttachments).Where(s => !s.DeletedFlag).Select(s => s.StudentFk).Distinct().Count(),
                           RequiredStudents = i.Key.Item.SCS_Attachments.Where(a => a.IsRequired).SelectMany(a => a.SCS_StudentAttachments).Where(s => !s.DeletedFlag).Select(s => s.StudentFk).Distinct().Count(),
                           IsPublic = i.Key.Item.IsPublic,
                           AllowRecurring = i.Key.Item.AllowRecurringPayments,
                           EffectiveCutoff = i.Key.Item.SCS_Attachments.Where(a => !a.DeletedFlag && a.CourseDropCutoff.HasValue).Select(a => a.CourseDropCutoff).OrderBy(a => a).FirstOrDefault(),
                           CreatedDate = i.Key.Item.CreatedDate
                       }).OrderBy(i => i.ItemPk).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: You say you want to group by itempk, which is nowhere mentioned in your group by clause.  I am confused as to how you believe this is supposed to work, and it's therefore hard to tell you where you've gone wrong. If there's a particular key you want to group on, that key has to be somewhere in the group clause.

Answer (score 0):

your groupbyy is indeed doing nothing for you, you need to tell the groupby what to group by....

like

```
.GroupBy(n => n.Category)
```

Comment: Cool I understand that but what a bout grouping by the category and item?

Comment: not sure what you are expecting?  you only have item and category? grouping by them both is pointless?

Answer (score -3):

Here is a simple example to your grouping question:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var allItems = GetAllItems();
        var groups = from item in allItems
            group item by item.Category
            into newGroup
            select newGroup;

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\nCategory: {group.Key}");
            foreach (var item in group)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}: {item.Price}");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static List<Category> GetAllCategories()
    {
        return new List<Category>()
        {
            new Category() { Id = 1, Name = "Programming Books" },
            new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "Fiction Books" }
        };
    }

    static List<Item> GetAllItems()
    {
        return new List<Item>()
            {
                new Item() { Id = 1, Name = "Embedded Linux", Category = 1, Price = 9.9 },
                new Item() { Id = 2, Name = "LINQ In Action", Category = 1, Price = 36.19 },
                new Item() { Id = 3, Name = "C# 6.0 and the .NET 4.6 Framework", Category = 1, Price = 40.99 },
                new Item() { Id = 4, Name = "Thinking in LINQ", Category = 1, Price = 36.99 },
                new Item() { Id = 5, Name = "The Book Thief", Category = 2, Price = 7.99 },
                new Item() { Id = 6, Name = "All the Light We Cannot See", Category = 2, Price = 16.99 },
                new Item() { Id = 7, Name = "The Life We Bury", Category = 2, Price = 8.96 }
            };
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This example is simple enough for anyone new to LINQ. I am sure you can make some adjustment to make it work for your specific issue. Hope this will help.

Comment: and the grouping is where?